# Can I bulk import SLD files into GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'd like to import several SLD files into GeoServer (Various styles for OS Open Zoomstack, thanks @OrdnanceSurvey!)

Is the only option to import them one at at time using the GeoServer interface? I copied the files into the Styles folder, but that didn't work.

Am I missing something, or is this it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a script talking to the REST API: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/styles.html

Or you can generate the necessary XML files with a custom script as well, it's not hard, I did so recently writing a small Java class (as it's my programming language of trade). And nope, I cannot share the source code of it, sorry....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some [code](https://gitlab.com/ijturton/geoserver-loader) last year that should get you started, see my [blog](https://blog.ianturton.com/geoserver/2018/09/11/OS-Zoomstack.html) for more details.

It uses [GeoServer Manager](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki) to handle the rest calls:

```
 private void createStyle(String table, File styleDir) {
    // We always search for name + "." otherwise rail matches railstations etc.
    File styleFile = null;
    for (File file : styleDir.listFiles()) {
      if (file.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(table + ".")) {
        styleFile = file;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (styleFile == null) {
      // try with out an s on the end of the layername
      for (File file : styleDir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(table.substring(0, table.length() - 2) + ".")) {
          styleFile = file;
          break;
        }
      }

    }
    if (styleFile != null) {
      if (reader.existsStyle(table)) {
        publisher.updateStyle(styleFile, table);
      } else {
        publisher.publishStyle(styleFile, table);
      }
    } else {
      System.err.println("no style found for " + table);
    }
  }
```